# How to obtain all available Elastic IP addresses in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

What is the boto3 equivalent to:

```
import boto

conn = boto.connect_ec2()
addresses = conn.get_all_addresses()
```

(returning all Elastic IP addresses)

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
addresses = ec2.????
```

I am a little bit confused by the generalization that seem to apply to VPC setups as well.

---

What I found so far is following:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2')
print client.describe_addresses()
```

This response does not seem to contain the association status.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a simple example that prints all Elastic IP public IP addresses in the current account/region:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2')
addresses_dict = client.describe_addresses()
for eip_dict in addresses_dict['Addresses']:
    print(eip_dict['PublicIp'])
```

For more, see the [EC2.Client.describe_addresses reference documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_addresses).

Answer (score 2):

This may help:

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name="ap-southeast-1")
client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name="ap-southeast-1")
# create 3 x Elastic IP Addresses.  Set to Domain='vpc' to allocate the address for use with instances in a VPC.
eip1 = client.allocate_address(Domain='vpc')
eip2 = client.allocate_address(Domain='vpc')
eip3 = client.allocate_address(Domain='vpc')

# A collection of VpcAddresses resources "vpc_addresses.all()"
print eip = list(ec2.vpc_addresses.all())
[ec2.VpcAddress(allocation_id='eipalloc-3f693f5a'), ec2.VpcAddress(allocation_id='eipalloc-7896c01d'), 
ec2.VpcAddress(allocation_id='eipalloc-9997c1fc')]
```

[Reference Link 1](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.allocate_address)

[Reference Link 2](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html?highlight=vpc_addresses#EC2.ServiceResource.vpc_addresses)

Comment: Can you explain your answer so that others can learn from it? Just dumping code may not be too helpful for understanding.